# Change working directory to file importing my module

Tags: python, file, path, working-directory

I've found plenty of similar questions online but I'm unsure if they solve my problem. I'm coding a Python module with that structure :

```
mymodule
|--- __init__.py
|--- resources
      |—-- myfont.ttf
|--- ...
```

It uses pygame and need to load a font file. So my `__init__.py` file starts like that :

```py
import os
import pygame

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))  # change working directory to use resources/myfont.ttf

pygame.init()  # init the pygame module
font = pygame.font.Font("./resources/myfont.ttf", 10)  # load myfont.ttf with size 10
```

The thing is that I want to change the working directory back to where my module is imported from, because some functions may, for example, save pictures to the working directory, and the user of my module should not have to dig into my module files to find that picture.

Should I just change it back with something like

```py
import sys

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))
```

and redo that whole manipulation every time I need some of my own files again ? Isn't there a simpler way of doing that ?

---

Edit : Thanks to [Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11082165/brian), the way is

```py
from importlib.resources import files
import pygame

font_traversable = file("mymodule.resources").joinpath("myfont.ttf")

pygame.init()
font = pygame.font.Font(font_traversable, 10)
```

Comment: You might want to look into using Python's builtin package resources system: [`importlib.resources`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.resources.html)

Comment: @Brian Thank you, I will look into that ! At first sight it exactly looks like what I need.